# INSERT multiple rows with SELECT and an array

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, bulkinsert

In EXCEL/VBA I can program my way out of a thunderstorm, but in SQL I am still a novice.  So apologies, after much Googling I can only get partway to a solution which I presume ultimately will be pretty simple, just not wrapping my head around it.

I need to create an INSERT script to add multiple rows in a 3-column table.  A simple insert would be:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(StoreId, ItemID, 27)
```

First hurdle is dynamically repeat this for every StoreID in a different table.  Which I think becomes this:

```
INSERT INTO table 
SELECT (SELECT StoreID FROM Directory.Divisions), ItemID, 27)
```

If that is actually correct and would effectively create the 50-60 rows for each store, then I'm almost there.  The problem is the ItemID.  This will actually be an array of ItemIDs I want to feed in manually.  So if there are 50 stores and 3 ItemIDs, it would enter 150 rows.  Something like:

```
ItemID = (123,456,789,246,135)
```

So how can I merge these two ideas? Pull the StoreIDs from another table, feed in the array of items for the second parameter, then my hardcoded 27 at the end.  50 stores and 10 items should create 500 rows.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Quick note about site culture here: you don't need to apologize for your lack of experience in a particular domain; it's okay (preferred, even) just to focus on the details of the problem you're facing.

Comment: `VALUES` implies you are doing manual input. Are StoreID and ItemID coming from a specific table? If so, you are probably going to have to do `INSERT INTO [table] SELECT StoreID, ItemID, 27 as [column_name] FROM [other_table]`

Comment: ItemID predefined or are they stored in a table somewhere?

Comment: No, the ItemIDs I want as an array I can edit directly in the script. The StoreIDs I am pulling from another table as shown.  I thought perhaps setting an array at the top of some kind, so it's easy to edit those item ids when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `into` to insert into the target table. To generate itemid's you will have to use `union all` with your values and `cross join` on the `divisions` table.

```
select 
d.storeid, 
x.itemid, 
27 as somecolumn
into targettablename
from Directory.Divisions d
cross join (select 123 as itemid union all select 456 union all select 789...) x
```

Edit: If the table to `insert` into isn't created yet, it should be created before inserting the data.

```
create table targettable as (store_id varchar(20), item_id varchar(20), 
                             somecolumn int);

insert into targettable (store_id, item_id, somecolumn)
select 
d.storeid, 
x.itemid, 
27
from Directory.Divisions d
cross join (select 123 as itemid union all select 456 union all select 789...) x
```

Comment: This looks perfect.  When I run it without the INTO line, I get a perfect output showing all stores linked to all items, 1000s of correct entries.  But when I add the INTO line, I get an error `An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name.`

Comment: i modified the query to use an `alias` for `27`. try it.

Comment: Great, thanks.  It seems like this is trying to create a new table rather than insert into an existing table.   `targettablename` is an existing table, when I run the script it says: `There is already an object named 'targettablename' in the database.`

Comment: Ok, worked that out.  The Syntax looks solid, but I'm running into foreign key constraints, I'll figure out where that is coming from.  Thanks.

Comment: Worked perfectly in the end.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need your array of item ids in a table of some sort. Either a permanent table, table variable or temporary table. For example using a temporary table, which you prefix with a hash symbol:

```
CREATE TABLE #ItemIds (item_id int)
INSERT INTO #ItemIds VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO #ItemIds VALUES (2)
...
INSERT INTO #ItemIds VALUES (10)
```

Then this should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT StoreId, item_Id, 27
FROM Directory.Divisions, #ItemIds
```

The results set from the SELECT will be inserted into 'table'. This is an example of a cartesian join. Because there is no join condition, every row from Directory.Divisions is joined to every row in #ItemIds. Hence if you have 50 stores and 10 items, that will result in 50 x 10 = 500 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You may declare table variable for item IDs and use CROSS JOIN to multiply division records to items: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99438/1

```
create table Divisions(StoreId int)
insert into Divisions values (1), (2), (3)

declare @items table(ItemID int)
insert into @items values (5), (6), (7)

-- insert into target(stireid, itemid, otherColumn)
select d.StoreId, i.ItemID, 27
from Divisions d 
cross join @items i
```